# How to view video in circular view android

Tags: android, video

i am trying to view my video in small circle but it displayed in rectangle form and i have given background to circle video-view  but it not display in that circle

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">


                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/video_shape"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This will not work .. You need to draw an overlay bitmap over it ... Or just try to use an Image with transparent circle in center ....

Comment: also, have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53632357/10300673